# Run single test of a specific test suite in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, automated-tests, jestjs

I have a file called "test-file-1", within it i have a few describes (test suites) with unique names and inside them i have tests which may have similar names across test suites.

To run a single test suite or test i type the command below.

```
npm test -- -t "Test Suite or Test"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run a single test of a specific test suite.

Comment: So did you read the CLI docs? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html

Comment: Yes, but i didn't found a way to run a single test of a specific test suite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things i found out that it was simpler than i thought.

You simply have to put the test after the test suite in the same string:

```
npm test -- -t "<Test Suite> <Test>"
```

Comment: If we haven't describe the test then this will not work. Use describe in testcase file to create test suite. e.g. describe('sumFile', () => { //test here });

Answer (score 22):

Give the path of the file you want to test :

`npm test path/of/your/testfile.js -t "test name"`

will run only the test (or group) named "test name" of this specific file.

Comment: that's the problem, i have a file with multiple tests with the same or similar name, the   only thing that differs them is the test suite.

Comment: easily get the path of the file in VSC. Right click the file and select "Copy Relative Path".

Answer (score 5):

```
import LoggerService from '../LoggerService ';

describe('Method called****', () => {
  it('00000000', () => {
    const logEvent = jest.spyOn(LoggerService , 'logEvent');
    expect(logEvent).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

run below command
npm test -- tests/LoggerService.test.ts -t '00000000'

Answer (score 1):

Point to the test suite in jest config file via   `"testMatch":["**/path/testSuite/*.js"]`

and now execute by giving unique testname by `jest testName`

Here you have to update the testMatch every time which is your testSuite

Comment: i'm looking for a simpler way, manually changing every time is not practical.

Comment: your testsuite is dynamic and testcase is static so you have to change the testsuite all the time then why dont you run using  `jest -t /path/to/testSuite/testcase.js`  . Everytime you have to only pass testsuite here and remove testMatch from config file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a jest config file, you can use the `testNamePattern` key to configure this. So your config file could look something like

jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
  "testNamePattern": "login",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "testTimeout": 30000
}
```

This will only run test that has "login" in one of the test pattern

Reference:
https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testnamepatternregex

Answer (score 0):

For me, it only works with:

```
npm run test -- tests/01_login.js --testcase "Should login into Dashboard"

npm run <script> -- <test suite path> --testcase "<test case>"
```

my script in package.json:

```
"test": "env-cmd -f ./.env nightwatch --retries 2 --env selenium.chrome",
```

at nightwatch version 1.3.4

Answer (score -2):

in latest versions of jest you could use `it.only()`, `describe.only()`, etc in which case it will just execute that single test without having to pass a file or filter parameter