# Test specific file using Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

In my project folder I have lots of subfolders with js code and test.js file in each of them. I want to be able to test specific file. For example, let's say in our project folder we have 'fib' folder:

```
C:.
└───exercises
    └───fib
            fib-test.js
            index.js
```

Now, from the exercises folder I execute jest command:

```
jest fib\fib-test.js
```

And I get:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\exercises
  62 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 26 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 62 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: fib\fib-test.js - 0 matches
```

If I do just jest, I'll get all tests ran. If I move fib folder out of the exercises folder it works as expected. Here is the code for all of the files:

**index.js:**

```
function fib(n) {}

module.exports = fib;
```

**test.js:**

```
const fib = require('./index');

test('Fib function is defined', () => {
  expect(typeof fib).toEqual('function');
});

test('calculates correct fib value for 1', () => {
  expect(fib(1)).toEqual(1);
});

test('calculates correct fib value for 2', () => {
  expect(fib(2)).toEqual(1);
});

test('calculates correct fib value for 3', () => {
  expect(fib(3)).toEqual(2);
});

test('calculates correct fib value for 4', () => {
  expect(fib(4)).toEqual(3);
});

test('calculates correct fib value for 15', () => {
  expect(fib(39)).toEqual(63245986);
});
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I've tried all of these solutions with no success:

1. [Run single test of a specific test suite in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045201/run-single-test-of-a-specific-test-suite-in-jest)
2. [How do I run a single test using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827054/how-do-i-run-a-single-test-using-jest/42897994)
3. [How do I test a single file using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725955/how-do-i-test-a-single-file-using-jest)

But was able to achieve the desired result running jest command with --watch flag and then in regex menu entering the relative path to the fib\test.js. The question is how to do it without entering watch menu?

Answer (score 4):

### **TL;DR** :

1. rename your test file `fib-test.js` to `fib.test.js`
2. run `jest fib.test.js`
3. volia, `jest` will run the file you specify
4. you can also test any number of test file you specify ***only***, by `jest XXX.test.js YYY.test.js`

### Long Story

I see that your question implicitly have a few assumptions. You can make the question more specific if you list them out explicitly:

1. you're running on a Windows machine
2. your project root or `jest.config.js` is in `C:\exercises`

For (1), I don't have a Windows machine on hand, please run & validate my solution.

Assumptions aside, the error occurs at your test file name: `fib-test.js`. `jest` is looking for `XXX.test.js` and will not match & test `XXX-test.js`. You can find the clue at error message:

```
testMatch: ... **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) ...
```

Once you rename your file to `fib.test.js`, `jest fib.test.js` will search any child folders from your project root directory, or where `jest.config.js` at; and match & test the specific test file.

My `jest` version: `"ts-jest": "^27.0.3"`

#### Small trick #1

Look at the full error message again:

```
testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 26 matches
```

You can actually group all your test cases into `<rootDir>/__tests__/` and put `__test__` into `.gitignore` so that your test cases can be kept secret and not pushed to Git.

#### Small trick #2

Because `jest` looks at every child folders, you can actually put folder name before your test file:

`jest fib/fib.test.js` is essentially equivalent to `jest fib.test.js`

Though, ***jest*** don't see any reason to bother yourself so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **jest.config.js**, a simply manner is just to separate in several **testMatch** and comment/uncomment as needed.

```
module.exports = {
  // verbose: true,
  // silent: true,
  // forceExit: true,
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  // testMatch: ['**/__tests__/Classes/**/Rules.test.js'],
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/Classes/**/Robot.test.js'], // testing this file
  // testMatch: ['**/__tests__/api.test.js'],
  // testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.test.js'], // testing ALL test files!
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.js'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/']
}
```